# How can I test if child React component was rendered based on a URL change using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, enzyme, react-router-v4

I want to test if i get the `NotFoundScreen` component rendered when i change the URL to a path that does not exists

This is my App component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import HomeScreen from '../HomeScreen';
import NotFoundScreen from '../NotFoundScreen';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={HomeScreen} />
          <Route component={NotFoundScreen} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my not working test:

```js
  it('render NotFoundScreen when goes to a wrong path', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);

    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/wrongpath';
    await wrapper.update();

    expect(wrapper.find(NotFoundScreen).length).toEqual(1);
  });
```

When I change to check HomeScreen component it passes, its like the `wrapper` doesn't update according to the URL

```js
expect(wrapper.find(HomeScreen).length).toEqual(1);
```

Comment: The workflow is going right, but i can't find a way to test this with jest and enzyme

Comment: It seems to be a problem with jest jsdom

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem is with jsdom.

Here is the workaround:

```js
  it('render NotFoundScreen when goes to a wrong path', async () => {
    history.replaceState({}, 'WrongPath', '/wrongpath');
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    expect(wrapper.find(NotFoundScreen).length).toEqual(1);
  });
```